# E/JavaBinder: !!! failed binder transaction !!! (parcel size = 1714072)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to open an activity from the Image Cropper library to take images from fragments. When I click on the button to start that activity, the app is crashing and giving that error.

```
PID: 30654
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1714072 bytes
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:160)

Complete Error:
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1713760 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1129)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:4027)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:144)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a limit on the size of a bundle and the data passed into an Intent.  Last I checked (it may have changed) that limit was around 1MB.  If you need to pass more data than that, you need to send it in some other manner, such as writing it to a file and sending the filename to the activity instead.

Comment: I am not sending the data on Intent. I am just getting the single image.

Comment: @Muaz You're trying to open an Activity.  That's done by sending data via an intent.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this issue when I was trying to parcel around 4000+ objects while firing another activity with intent. So I strongly feel there's some limit to sending the data via intents.

So the main issue is not with intents it is how you parcel your data before/or at the time of transmitting data.